# How to display multiple records using foreach loop in fpdf using php and sql

Tags: php, fpdf

Im working with fpdf that display multiple records using foreach loop, but it says "Connection is busy with results for another command". Here is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmts = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM inv_dealerscardsuppliers WHERE id = :id");
$stmts->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmts->execute();
$resultsuppliers = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


foreach ($resultsuppliers as $rowsuppliers) {
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['major'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');      
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['brand'], border:'1', ln:'0', align:'L');
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['terms'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['credit'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmts = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM inv_dealerscardsuppliers WHERE id = :id");
$stmts->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmts->execute();
$resultsuppliers = $stmts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


foreach ($resultsuppliers as $rowsuppliers) {
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['major'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');      
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['brand'], border:'1', ln:'0', align:'L');
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['terms'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');
            $pdf->cell(w:'47.5', h:'6', txt:$rowsuppliers['credit'], border:'1', ln:'0',align:'L');
        }
```

Comment: fetchAll is the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).